# Add a prefix to a views field pre_render

Tags: views

Our Drupal distribution is to be used with different currencies defined by a custom variable...when we display nodes in a view with the price field we don't add the currency prefix...i want to add it through im guessing hook_views_pre_render? How can i inject a prefix using my custom variable?

[image: This is what one of our views looks like]

This is what i am thinking:

```
if (in_array($view->name, $views_with_prices)) {
//dsm($view->result);
foreach ($view->result as $activity) {
  //dsm($activity);
  $price = $activity->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_average_price['und'][0]['value'];
  if ($price != 0) {
    $activity->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_average_price['und'][0]['value'] = variable_get('my_currency') .  $activity->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_average_price['und'][0]['value'];
  }
}
}
```

but ideally i'd like to use a specific prefix functionality that comes with cck fields if possible or views equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by creating a template file, like `views-view-field--fieldname.tpl.php`, for the field and add the currency prefix to it.